# C# Reading all nodes inner text under a parent

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml file that looks like

```
<root>
 <allnames>
  <name1>george</name1>
  <name2>lukas</name2>
  <name3>nick</name3>
 </allnames>
</root>
```

I am trying to add in an array under the Node "Allnames" every child
so the array will look like
{ "george", "lukas", "nick" } (3 items).

Instead using this code

```
public string[] getStrings(string path)
        try
        {
            List<string> whatToReturn = new List<string>();

            XmlNodeList nodelist = xml.SelectNodes(path);

            foreach (XmlNode node in nodelist)
            {
                whatToReturn.Add(node.InnerText);
            }


            return whatToReturn.ToArray();
        }
        catch (System.NullReferenceException)
        {
            return null;
        }
}
```

It returns : { "georgelukasnick" } (1 item).

All i want to is to return 3 items instead of 1..Any help?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? Tried stepping through to see what's being added to the list and when? Also, what's the value of the `path` parameter?

Comment: @MattJones The value is "root/allnames"

Comment: Please show the caller of `getStrings`; the error doesn't seem to be in the code that you posted.

Comment: string[] test;
test = xml_manager.getStrings("root/test");

Comment: how do you print the values of the test variable?

Comment: You should never be catching a null reference exception like that.

Comment: The code i am printing the values is right...
If i use multiple times the node "name" then it correctly adds the items in the array

Comment: I've added a simple solution using LINQ if you're interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Xpath that selects the child nodes of "allnames".
Like this:

```
xml.SelectNodes("root/allnames/*");
```

Answer (score 3):

You're accessing the text incorrectly.

Basically, you're selecting the `AllNames` element (a single node) and then adding its `InnerText` value to the list - but the `InnerText` of `AllNames` is **all** of the inner texts concatenated.

You should select the `AllNames` element and then iterate through its child elements - you can do this with XPath:

```
XmlNodeList nodeList = xml.SelectNodes("root/allnames/child::node()");
```

You can also do this using LINQ to XML via the XDocument class in a simpler fashion (where my `xmlString` variable is your sample XML):

```
    var xDocument = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
    var strings = xDocument.Descendants("allnames").First().Elements().Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
```

Well, simpler to me ;)